# Solving the reduced sextic $z^6+z^2+az+b=0$ using the two-parameter Kampé de Fériet function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, special-functions, analytic-functions

First, some background.

**I. One-Parameter forms**

The *Bring-Jerrard quintic*, $x^5+x+\alpha=0,$ has a solution as,

$$x = -\alpha\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{(5k)!}{k!(4k+1)!}\;\alpha^{4k}$$

This series has a narrow radius of convergence, namely $|\alpha|<\left(\frac{4^4}{5^5}\right)^{1/4}\approx 0.53$. But it can be extended via analytic continuation using the *generalized hypergeometric function* ${_pF_q},$

$$x = -\alpha\,{_4F_3}\Big(\frac15,\frac25,\frac35,\frac45;\,\frac24,\frac34,\frac54;\,-\frac{5^5}{4^4}\alpha^4\Big)$$

for more general $\alpha$, thus solving the general quintic.

---

**II. Two-Parameter forms**

The quintic and sextic two-parameter equations,

$$By^5+Ay^2+y+1 = 0$$
$$Bz^6+Az^2+z+1 = 0$$

can be solved as,

$$y = -\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(2j+5k)!}{j!k!(j+4k+1)!}\;A^j B^k$$

$$z = -\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty (+1)^k \frac{(2j+6k)!}{j!k! (j + 5 k + 1)!}\; A^j B^k$$

with the quintic root $y$ by Passare and Tsikh in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.2957), and the sextic root $z$ by Robert Israel in this [old MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1333454/4781). The second equation is just the general sextic in disguise since the general sextic can be reduced to the form,

$$z^6+z^2+\alpha z+\beta =0$$

Unfortunately, R. Israel's solution $z$ also has a narrow radius of convergence. So we are seeking an analytic continuation such that it will be valid for more general $(A,B)$ thus solving the general sextic.

---

**III. Questions**

1. If the analytic continuation for the quintic $x$ involves the **one**-parameter *generalized hypergeometric function*, does the analytic continuation for R. Israel's sextic $z$ involve the **two**-parameter [*Kampé de Fériet function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp%C3%A9_de_F%C3%A9riet_function)?
2. Or is it some other two-parameter function, maybe like the [*Appell series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series), [*Humbert series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series), etc?
3. The Kampé de Fériet function can solve the general sextic in its reduced form. In Mathematica syntax, what would be the input to solve, for example, $z^6+z^2+3z+2=0$?

Comment: Related questions about the Kampé de Fériet function [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1397297/4781) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1313118/4781).

Comment: couldn't you just write $z=\beta q/\alpha$, multiply through by $1/\beta$, and then you would be left with $$\frac{\beta^5}{\alpha^6}q^6+\frac{\beta}{\alpha^2}q^2+q+1=0$$

Comment: @clathratus Of course, that’s why i said it is just the general sextic in disguise. The problem is R. Israel’s soluton has a narrow radius of convergence. There has to be a way to extend it

Comment: [This article](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-geometry-and-symmetry-in-physics/volume-11/issue-none/Resolution-of-Degree-leq-6-Algebraic-Equations-by-Genus-Two/10.7546/jgsp-11-2008-77-93.pdf) solves the sextic using theta functions defined as a double sum.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thanks for the link. Considering the intricacies of the procedure, the author should have included a _single_ numerical example as added proof. Do you know [Niels Abel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Henrik_Abel#Cathedral_School_and_Royal_Frederick_University) actually thought he found the quintic formula in radicals? Two math professors could not find the flaw, until Degen asked for a numerical example. It was then Abel found the error, reversed direction, and proved it was impossible to solve. Just a thought. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asker wanted an analytic continuation, so we apply @Richard Stanley’s method in [“Series solution for general trinomial”](https://mathoverflow.net/a/418396/245836) with [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem):

$$\begin{align}z^6+z^2+az+b=0\implies z_k=e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i }6(z^2+az+b)^\frac16=\omega_k(z-p)^\frac16(z-q)^\frac16=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\omega_k^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}(z-p)^\frac n6(z-q)^\frac n6\right|_0,k=0,\dots ,6\end{align}$$

[General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) uses [factorial power $n^{(m)}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factorialpower):

$$\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}(z-p)^\frac n6(z-q)^\frac n6\right|_0=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}m\left(\frac n6\right)^{(n-m-1)}\left(\frac n6\right)^{(m)}(-p)^{m-\frac{5n}6+1}(-q)^{\frac n6-m}$$

Summing over $m$ presents a [regularized Gauss hypergeometric function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Hypergeometric2F1Regularized) ${_2\tilde{\text F}_1}$:

$$\bbox[2.5px,border:5px groove blue]{\begin{align}
&z^6+z^2+az+b=0\implies \\ 
z_k &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i n}6\frac{\left(\frac n6\right)!^2 (-p)^{m-\frac{5n}6+1}(-q)^{\frac n6-m}}{\left(m-\frac{5n}6+1\right)!\left(\frac n6-m\right)!\Gamma(n-m)m!n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac n6\right)!}{n!}\,e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i n}6(-p)^{1-\frac{5n}6}(-q)^\frac n6\,_2\tilde{\text F}_1\left(1-n,-\frac n6;2-\frac{5n}6;\frac pq\right)\\
\text{where},\\
p,q&=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}}2\end{align}}$$

It is interesting to note the $6n$ terms are $0$. Alternatively, using the *hypergeometric function* ${_2 F_1}$,

$$z_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac n6\right)!}{n!\,\Gamma\big(2-\frac{5n}6\big)}\,e^\frac{(2k+1)\pi i n}6(-p)^{1-\frac{5n}6}(-q)^\frac n6\,{_2 F_1}\left(1-n,-\frac n6;2-\frac{5n}6;\frac pq\right)$$

The example $z^6+z^2+3z+2=z^6+(z+2)(z+1)=0$ cannot be solved with Robert Israel’s series, as $\frac{32}{729}w^6+\frac29 w^2+w+1=0$ where $w=\frac32 z$ is outside the [series convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1333454/4781). However, our series gives [all $6$ roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Bsum%5B%28%28-%28-2%29%29%5E%281+-+%285+n%29%2F6%29+%28-%28-1%29%29%5E%28n%2F6%29+exp%28%282*%7B0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%7D%2B1%29+pi+i+n%2F6%29+%28n%2F6%29%21+Hypergeometric2F1Regularized%281+-+n%2C+-n%2F6%2C+2+-+%285+n%29%2F6%2C+%28-2%29%2F%28-1%29%29%29%2F%28n%21%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C250%7D%5D%2C10%5D) matching the [actual roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=z%5E6%2Bz%5E2%2B3+z%2B2%3D0). The series usually converge for about $|a|,|b|>1$.

Comment: The sums look like an [Appell hypergeometric series](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/AppellF1/06/01/03/01/0003/), but it is hard to see how to convert the factorials/gamma functions of $\frac n6$ into pochhammer symbols $(a)_n$ like in the link. At least we have a larger convergence region.

Comment: If one really wanted to, there is easily a “closed form” with a so called [Srivastava Daoust function](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/publ/29/29.pdf)

Comment: Nice! This seems faster since it is not a double-summation, has broader convergence, though still not the complete solution to the reduced sextic. (P.S. I made some minor changes to the infobox, and added the form using the hypergeometric function ${_2F_1}$.

Comment: I have an important question. Will your analysis still work if we go higher to the reduced septic, or $x^7+(a+x)(b+x)(c+x) = 0$? Will a hypergeometric function still solve it, or no more? If it can, i will ask a separate question.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Yes, as a triple hypergeometric series because the Lagrange reversion coefficients would be $\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}(x+a)^\frac17(x+b)^\frac16(x+c)^\frac17\right|_{x=0}$. Applying [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) twice, or multinomial product rule formula from the link, will get you a double sum for the series coefficients.

Comment: I have made the new question. Kindly check [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4728991/4781).

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII If it is of interest, the Mathematica function [inverse beta regularized](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseBetaRegularized.html) can [solve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=evaluate+0%3Dc%2BB+betaregularized%28A%2Fx%2C4%2C3%29%2C+B%3Db%2F%2815+A%5E4%29%2CA%3D-5a%2F%288+b%29) $f(x)=cx^6+b x^2+a x+\frac{25 a^2}{96 b}=0$ for some $x$. If one expands the regularized beta function in the “solve” link, it would be equivalent to solving $f(x)$. However, one more free parameter is needed for solving $g(x)=x^6+x^2+ax+b=0$. Maybe $f(x)$ can transform into $g(x)$.

Comment: We can set $c=1$ without loss of generality. The problem is the constant term is a function of the $x^2,x$ terms. Scaling variables will not do it. And it already took a quartic Tschirnhausen to eliminate 3 terms; to satisfy this additional constraint may require a higher one, so I'm afraid we're stuck. Your sextic does have the nice form $$96b x^6 + 24(2b x + a)^2 + a^2 = 0$$ and its Galois group has order 6!=720, the highest for deg 6.

Comment: To all: there is probably a way to find all complex solutions in the form $z=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}x^{-s}\text{Gauss hypergeometric function expression}ds$ or, expanding the integrand, as a double integral. This solution can be written if some users wish

Comment: Kindly go ahead. It is allowed to give two answers if the other gives another perspective.

Comment: If the [“two parameter fox h function”](https://eudml.org/doc/115180) were standardized, then we likely would have a closed form using the double integral which may be attempted at another time.

Comment: Even though it is not the Kampé de Fériet function, it is still a very useful answer that applies to degrees $5,6,7,8$. I should have clicked on the button a long time ago. Mea culpa.